# Running custom validations with gem specific methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I setup a custom validation that checks if a user has voted for an album before submitting a review. The validation works fine on the client side but when it comes to running my Rspec tests I seem to run into some problems.

The validation makes use of the Acts As Votable gem's [voted_for?](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#the-voter) method. Unfortunately this is where things go bad. For my non-custom validations (that do work regularly btw) I get an error like this:

```
  3) Review validations should ensure body has a length of at least 40
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_length_of(:body).is_at_least(40) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `voted_for' for nil:NilClass
```

What do I need to do in order for this method to be recognized?

**Review Model**

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id

  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 40 }

  def album_vote
    if !owner.voted_for?(album)
      errors.add(:review, "requires an album vote before submitting")
    end
  end
end
```

**Review Factory**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :review do
    body { Faker::Lorem.paragraph(2) }

    album
    association :owner, factory: :user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that there actually is an owner. The error is simply because you are calling on nil and does not really have anything to do with `ActsAsVotable`.

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 40 }
  validates :owner, presence: true

  def album_vote
    # consider raising an error if there is no owner.
    if owner && !owner.voted_for(album)
      errors.add(:review, "requires an album vote before submitting")
    end
  end
end
```

And then change your factory definition to create the owner:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:owner] do
    # ...
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :review do
    body { Faker::Lorem.paragraph(2) }
    album
    owner
  end
end
```

Comment: The error might also be related to how you are invoking the factory in your test.

Comment: Yeah it looks like it needed to check for a pre-existing `owner` in the conditional. Thanks Max!